# how do i make the div column with fixed height, also respond according to the content inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

i have created the following layout and i want the div columns "title 1" "title 2" have a fixed height and also grow when there is content inside of them, now when i add content to it the content goes past the height of the div. i want the content to be inside the div and grow accordingly. i have tried min-height but it didn't work i'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/**** Main Layout container ****/

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/**** Sidebar Static Left ****/

.sidebar {
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*** Fluid Container ***/

.fluid-container {
  width: 88%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #484545;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header h1 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  width: 180px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}


/*** Title Box Containers ***/

.box-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(229 221 221);
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 5%);
}

div#box1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  div#box1 {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(229 221 221);
  margin: 0 7px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 220px;
}

#item2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  min-width: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}

#item1 {
  height: calc(100% - 50%);
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#item3 {
  height: calc(100% - 30%);
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

h3 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #484545;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}


/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

span {
  float: right;
  margin: -41px 17px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: black;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar bg-slate-50">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas suscipit aliquid nobis eius harum ipsam eum perferendis modi excepturi laudantium, rerum recusandae nulla odio ullam aliquam aut quam ea cupiditate officiis? Tempora corrupti, officiis
      placeat quam praesentium quis dolores itaque repudiandae libero voluptates consequatur repellat, temporibus et laboriosam, accusantium ducimus quia distinctio a iste quaerat culpa ex cum. Officia laborum nesciunt quidem. Aliquid possimus soluta
      dolores obcaecati doloribus aut corrupti, at tenetur odit optio, facilis ipsam natus illum magni voluptas, quos animi. Sunt laudantium ut itaque, aperiam provident, nisi officiis inventore perspiciatis tenetur quidem sapiente natus vel ipsum omnis
      ad quia nemo ipsam in harum? Distinctio tempora quis facere animi molestiae iste quas voluptas iusto quaerat, officia modi aliquam earum saepe at est, suscipit vitae optio alias doloribus ea molestias illum impedit? Culpa sint, iure, illo provident
      officia minima consectetur, ea autem ut atque dolore quaerat dolor adipisci odio accusantium dolores dolorum odit rem dignissimos soluta. Veniam laborum, sint qui ad nemo ipsam voluptates magnam iure consectetur reprehenderit adipisci sed quos placeat
      ipsa aperiam repudiandae officia? Eum dicta quod, laudantium
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header Section</h1>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span onclick="openNav()">
                    <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
                </span>
    </div>


    <div class="box-container">
      <div id="box1" class="box">
        <div id="item1" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laborum doloremque quas tempora deleniti molestiae ullam nostrum repellat quae commodi, quaerat labore, rerum voluptatibus perferendis ex cupiditate excepturi officiis! Obcaecati
            quisquam sit vero a, vitae laborum eius reiciendis placeat nemo provident ea labore incidunt? Distinctio, explicabo? Ab asperiores eos quasi eum blanditiis ipsum ut reprehenderit nostrum dignissimos cupiditate, ipsa facere inventore laudantium
            ducimus dicta sunt quidem, nam harum. Esse iure, voluptate ducimus a voluptatem expedita quas nam officia obcaecati saepe necessitatibus exercitationem quo iusto, libero omnis? Earum esse, dolor quo non vitae repellat odit. Ad voluptates iure
            tenetur explicabo excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="box2" class="box">
        <div id="item1" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title A</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title B</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laborum doloremque quas tempora deleniti molestiae ullam nostrum repellat quae commodi, quaerat labore, rerum voluptatibus perferendis ex cupiditate excepturi officiis! Obcaecati
            quisquam sit vero a, vitae laborum eius reiciendis placeat nemo provident ea labore incidunt? Distinctio, explicabo? Ab asperiores eos quasi eum blanditiis ipsum ut reprehenderit nostrum dignissimos cupiditate, ipsa facere inventore laudantium
            ducimus dicta sunt quidem, nam harum. Esse iure, voluptate ducimus a voluptatem expedita quas nam officia obcaecati saepe necessitatibus exercitationem quo iusto, libero omnis? Earum esse, dolor quo non vitae repellat odit. Ad voluptates iure
            tenetur explicabo excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title C</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }


  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
</script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: fit-content;` on  `#item2`. This way both divs will grow/shrink based on the content inside.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}


function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/**** Main Layout container ****/

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/**** Sidebar Static Left ****/

.sidebar {
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*** Fluid Container ***/

.fluid-container {
  width: 88%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #484545;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header h1 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  width: 180px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}


/*** Title Box Containers ***/

.box-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(229 221 221);
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 5%);
}

div#box1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  div#box1 {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(229 221 221);
  margin: 0 7px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 220px;
}

#item2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: fit-content;
  min-width: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}

#item1 {
  height: calc(100% - 50%);
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#item3 {
  height: calc(100% - 30%);
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

h3 {
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #484545;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}


/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

span {
  float: right;
  margin: -41px 17px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: black;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar bg-slate-50">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas suscipit aliquid nobis eius harum ipsam eum perferendis modi excepturi laudantium, rerum recusandae nulla odio ullam aliquam aut quam ea cupiditate officiis? Tempora corrupti, officiis
      placeat quam praesentium quis dolores itaque repudiandae libero voluptates consequatur repellat, temporibus et laboriosam, accusantium ducimus quia distinctio a iste quaerat culpa ex cum. Officia laborum nesciunt quidem. Aliquid possimus soluta
      dolores obcaecati doloribus aut corrupti, at tenetur odit optio, facilis ipsam natus illum magni voluptas, quos animi. Sunt laudantium ut itaque, aperiam provident, nisi officiis inventore perspiciatis tenetur quidem sapiente natus vel ipsum omnis
      ad quia nemo ipsam in harum? Distinctio tempora quis facere animi molestiae iste quas voluptas iusto quaerat, officia modi aliquam earum saepe at est, suscipit vitae optio alias doloribus ea molestias illum impedit? Culpa sint, iure, illo provident
      officia minima consectetur, ea autem ut atque dolore quaerat dolor adipisci odio accusantium dolores dolorum odit rem dignissimos soluta. Veniam laborum, sint qui ad nemo ipsam voluptates magnam iure consectetur reprehenderit adipisci sed quos placeat
      ipsa aperiam repudiandae officia? Eum dicta quod, laudantium
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header Section</h1>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span onclick="openNav()">
                    <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
                </span>
    </div>


    <div class="box-container">
      <div id="box1" class="box">
        <div id="item1" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laborum doloremque quas tempora deleniti molestiae ullam nostrum repellat quae commodi, quaerat labore, rerum voluptatibus perferendis ex cupiditate excepturi officiis! Obcaecati
            quisquam sit vero a, vitae laborum eius reiciendis placeat nemo provident ea labore incidunt? Distinctio, explicabo? Ab asperiores eos quasi eum blanditiis ipsum ut reprehenderit nostrum dignissimos cupiditate, ipsa facere inventore laudantium
            ducimus dicta sunt quidem, nam harum. Esse iure, voluptate ducimus a voluptatem expedita quas nam officia obcaecati saepe necessitatibus exercitationem quo iusto, libero omnis? Earum esse, dolor quo non vitae repellat odit. Ad voluptates iure
            tenetur explicabo excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="box2" class="box">
        <div id="item1" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title A</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title B</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laborum doloremque quas tempora deleniti molestiae ullam nostrum repellat quae commodi, quaerat labore, rerum voluptatibus perferendis ex cupiditate excepturi officiis! Obcaecati
            quisquam sit vero a, vitae laborum eius reiciendis placeat nemo provident ea labore incidunt? Distinctio, explicabo? Ab asperiores eos quasi eum blanditiis ipsum ut reprehenderit nostrum dignissimos cupiditate, ipsa facere inventore laudantium
            ducimus dicta sunt quidem, nam harum. Esse iure, voluptate ducimus a voluptatem expedita quas nam officia obcaecati saepe necessitatibus exercitationem quo iusto, libero omnis? Earum esse, dolor quo non vitae repellat odit. Ad voluptates iure
            tenetur explicabo excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item bg-slate-50">
          <h3>Title C</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```